# PostgreSQL add different alias based on condition of many to many relation

Tags: postgresql

I have a many-to-many relation between product table and category table. To query all categories of a product, I can use this query

```
SELECT
  "Products_categorynew"."name",
  "Products_product"."id",
  "Products_product"."title"
FROM "Products_product"
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "Products_product_categories_new"
    ON ("Products_product"."id" = "Products_product_categories_new"."product_id")
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "Products_categorynew"
    ON ("Products_product_categories_new"."categorynew_id" = "Products_categorynew"."id");
```

However, in the category table, I have two kinds of categories. One is `"Products_categorynew"."parent_id"` is null and the other is not null.
If I want to make an alias on the first one as primary category and second as secondary category. How could I query it based on the query above? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Help us help you - share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for this sample

Comment: @Mureinik Yes, like 
ID    TITLE    primary category     secondary category
1      Nike     clothes                     clothes-pants
' clothes' and 'clothes-pants' are two categories with product in many to many relation.